# How to designate Facebook domain for Windows machine

Tags: windows, facebook, iis

I'm trying to do some dev on a Facebook enabled application on my Windows 7 machine.

When setting up the app in Facebook's control panel, it will not let me use "localhost" or "machinename" as a legitimate domain name.

On my Mac, I can use machine.local as a legitimate domain that Facebook accepts.

However on my Windows machine, IIS always resolves "machinename.local" to "machinename".  Facebook then doesn't acknowledge that my machine has permissions to the app.

So I either need to figure out how to get IIS to accept machinename.local and not redirect to machinename, or get Facebook to accept my domain.  (I'm on home dsl on a dynamic IP so I don't have a "real" domain)

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

On the Facebook page, put something like mycompany.com or local.mycompany.com.  Then edit your hosts file (c:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) with administrator priveledges and add an entry of `127.0.0.1  local.mycompany.com`

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bkaid!  Unfortunately, I'm still having the same problem.  When i click on the "Login" FB button in my app, it opens a new window that shows my FB account page instead of the normal login/approve dialog from FB.  It works fine on Mac and on Linux, but has this weird behavior on Win7. :(